# Sniff remote IP port for outgoing data VB

Tags: vb.net, tcp, network-programming

I am trying to monitor a remote IP port for outgoing data.

At the minute I have a TCP port connected which is stuck in a deliberate (almost) infinite loop.

This works, until the tcp connection is broken for any reason.

It just feels better to monitor the remote port for outgoing data, but all the classes/functions I find are for receiving data on a particular port.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can set up a task scheduler trigger and action on the remote machine.

Comment: Hi Paul. The remote machine is a barcode scanner, which I can't set up anything on. Should have mentioned this in the original post. Thats why I just need to monitor the outgoing port on the scanner. I think I am going to have to go down the route of polling the port to make sure I can see it.